# What if the 1993 World Trade Center bombing succeeded?

Tags: alternate-history, politics, geopolitics, terrorism

Considering it's been more than twenty years since that fateful day on September 11th, 2001, a thought came to mind: what do you think would have happened if the [failed WTC bombing in 1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_World_Trade_Center_bombing) succeeded and brought down one or two of the Twin Towers? How much would the tower(s) collapsing as opposed to a plane attack have affected the rest of Manhattan, America's response to this kind of attack, and the politics of the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to the attack, President Clinton grants extraordinary powers to the NSA and other intelligence agencies.

Internet mass surveillance starts in the same era as the [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September), killing the idea of a free and open cyberspace that bit earlier.

Phil Zimmerman goes to jail for his [February 1993 charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy#Criminal_investigation) of exporting arms.

As a result of the paranoid feel around the early internet, a larger offline, technophobic subculture persists into the 21st century.